# jQuery Drag & Drop - only allow drags from outside the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, drag

I am currently working on a website that uses the drag-and-drop functions of modern browsers in order to upload a file to a server with an ajax-call.

I am using the jQuery-Library and bind the appropriate events. There are a lot of them: dragstart, dragenter, dragover, dragleave etc...

I was wondering if I could only allow dragging files from "outside the browser". At the moment I have the problem that dom-elements are also draggable to my drop-area.

Is there any technical method to distinguish between external drags (outside -> browser) and internal drags (dom-element to dom-element)?

Comment: Post some code sample. Using `draggable="false"` you can disabled dragging for DOM elements.

Comment: Yes, Show your existing code.  most DOM elements aren't draggable by default.

Comment: Ok, I just created a small example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ge44j2wc/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can change your idea, the browser drag files have the suffix, you can determine whether a file names have the suffix after drag.

Comment: What do you mean by suffix? The file extension of the dragged file? I already heavily examined the different objects available in the different events. But I didn't see any suffix.

Answer (score 1):

At my case, I found a solution, using the html5 attributes changed to react  I could filter only the type I needed...

```
function checkDrag(event) {    
  if (event.dataTransfer.types[0] === 'Files') {
    //what you want do to
  }    
}

<Wrapper
  className="wrapper-body"
  onDragEnter={event => checkDrag(event)}
  ondragover={event => checkDrag(event)}
>
{Content} 
<Wrapper>
```

at my case, I worked only with start event but you can use the others html5 api methods to fill your needs, I guess :)

This link helped me a lot https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#droptargets